# htaccess redirect of search results

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having some trouble redirecting some old URLs to new ones.

This is the old path:

```
/index.php?loadpage=./includes/search.php&searchstring=KEYWORD
```

and I want it to redirect to this URL:

```
/search/node/KEYWORD
```

*where "KEYWORD" is a variable search string.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
RewriteRule ^/?search/node/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?loadpage=./includes/search.php&searchstring=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?search/node/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?searchstring=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but the redirects don't work.

Can anyone please help or give me some guidance on how to fix these redirects?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &searchstring=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /search/node/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Basically, first search for the `searchstring` parameter in query string.

The `searching` parameter value is put in a variable called `%1`

Then replace `index.php` with `/search/node/%1`

---

**E.g :**

From this :

```
http://domain.com/index.php?loadpage=./includes/search.php&searchstring=KEYWORD
```

I am redirected to this :

```
http://domain.com/search/node/KEYWORD
```

---

From this :

```
http://domain.com/index.php?loadpage=./includes/search.php&searchstring=SERVERFAULT
```

I am redirected to this :

```
http://domain.com/search/node/SERVERFAULT
```

---

Seems ok (hope) ! :)